# Scroll HorizontalListView on ButtonClick on either side

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` I want to scroll it towards left and Right on `Button` click.
I have refered this post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079486/scrolling-a-horizontalscrollview-by-clicking-buttons-on-its-sides)

But I'm not able to scroll it toward the left.As here `getScrollX()` gives the leftEdge of View.

So my Question is How could I make it scroll towards the left Side of `View` on btnClick.

Any Answer is Highly Appreciated..Thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help you ::

```
rightBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        hsv.scrollTo((int)hsv.getScrollX() + 10, (int)hsv.getScrollY());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public void scrollToLeft(){
    horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(horizontalScrollView.getScrollX() - 50, 0);
}
```

Comment: Which value is returned by getScrollX ? Is it always the same value ?

Comment: Distance from LeftEdge of HSV

Comment: Could you add a little bunch of code in your post ?

Answer (score -1):

Just try this code. it works.

declare first

**HorizontalScrollView hr;**

then inside on create

**hr=(HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontal1);**

and inside onclick of button , enter this code.

**hr.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_LEFT);**

Comment: Although this question is old one..but he is talking about HorizontalListView not scrollView..