# How to scroll horizontal recyclerview on click?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

Actually I want to add a such feature to horizontal `recyclerview` by which it would be scrolled to next position automatically if it's the last position sometimes it has to go forward and sometimes it has to come backward just like instagram's filter view which is scrolling automatically by the click . I wonder how to perform this task . Currently by my logic it's only scrolling forward but I don't know how to insert logic for backward scroll .

Code:

```
horzRview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(ctx, horzRview, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

            if(position<adapter.getItemCount()-1)
            horzRview.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(horzRview, null, position+1);

            else horzRview.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(horzRview, null, position-1);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrolling a HorizontalScrollView by clicking buttons on its sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079486/scrolling-a-horizontalscrollview-by-clicking-buttons-on-its-sides)

Comment: use `horzRview.scrollTo(curruntPostion-1)` method to scroll backword

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari thanks for your answer sir but when to do that

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari no sir you didn't understand how could i assume that I 've to move forward or backward

Comment: you don't need to assume. In `onItemClick()` just add this line `horzRview.scrollTo(curruntPostion-1)` only and remove other .

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari and what should be there in the y means `(pos-1,?)`

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari no It's not happening

Comment: No they are images

Comment: @HemantParmar No that question's answer is not satisfying my situation

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari Actually I wanna scroll in both the directions according to positions just like **instagram's filter showing menu**

Comment: then get screen width get its mid point if touch is before mid then use pos-1 or if its after mid use pos+1

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari sir could you please take some time to  explain it with an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing a tricky calculation i.e I'm getting the middle completely visible item by doing average of first and last completely visible item . Then I'm applying my logic as follows:

Code:

```
horzRview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(ctx, horzRview, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

            int avg =
                    (layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()+(layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()+1)+
                    layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition())/3;


            if(position>avg) horzRview.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(horzRview, null, position+1);
            else if(position!=0) horzRview.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(horzRview, null, position-1);
            else horzRview.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(horzRview, null, 0);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Create SmoothScroller with the preference STAP_TO_START:

```
RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new 
LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
   @Override protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
       return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
   }
};
```

Now you set the position where to scroll(Its position of the item):

```
smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
```

Pass that SmoothScroller to the LayoutManager:

```
layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
void onItemClick(View view , int position);
}
//in adapter class
public class Adpt extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<Adpt.ViewHolder> {
Context context;
OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
public Adpt(Context context,OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
this.context = context;
this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}
//put your click on itemview 
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {

      onItemClickListener.onItemClick(view,position);


  }
});
//implement your interface when you will set your adapter
Adpt adpt = new Adpr(activity,new OnItemCLickListner(){
// put your logic here
});
```

Comment: OP is asking for backward scroll logic for recyclerView not for item click listener. please provide description of your answer.