# android: button for scrolling at a certain position

Tags: android

I was planning to create a function where there's a 2 button at the side of the screen for up and down. I want it to just scroll up or down a little if I tap/touch it once and not totally at the top or bottom of the screen. I tried to search how to do it but all I saw was about getting at the top/bottom. Can you guys suggest me how can I implement this kind of function?

EDIT: i tried to use scrollTo but when i'm pressing the button the app goes not responding.

```
    FloatingActionButton buttondown1;
    ScrollView sv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigaze_scroll);

        buttondown1 = findViewById(R.id.buttondown);

        buttondown1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sv.scrollTo((int)sv.getScrollX(), (int)sv.getScrollY()+10);


            }
        });
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="16dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)."
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

        android:id="@+id/buttondown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabCustomSize="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/navigaze_up_btn"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This question is clearly answered here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16080847/7725103

Comment: i checked it but the app is not responding when i touch the button. i got no error when i build so i don't know whats the problem.

Comment: Please also post your xml layout.

Comment: done i already put my xml.

Comment: I have posted an answer compare yours to mine. Also I have seen above in your code you have not added findViewById for your ScrollView, make sure you check those.

Comment: "the app goes not responding" ... Really? It doesn't crash due to not initializing `sv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made this sample working scrolling state with two buttons top and bottom while clicking it will scroll text to specified value. And added TextView inside ScrollView.
So you can compare it with your code and see what you have done wrong.

**your_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/up_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Scroll Up" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="140dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lorem_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/down_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:text="Scroll Down" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**In your activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigaze_scroll);

    ScrollView scrollView = view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
    Button scrollUp = view.findViewById(R.id.up_button);
    Button scrollDown = view.findViewById(R.id.down_button);

    scrollUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getScrollY() -24);
        }
    });

    scrollDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getScrollY() + 24);
        }
    });
}
```

Ignore scroll for x since you are vertical scrolling.
Alternatively you can also check if scroll y top is scrolled previously by getting it's current scroll position.

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: thanks for the help. my problem is what you said that i forgot to put findviewid on my scrollview. thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Great you fixed it!